# Java RegEx for Email Detection

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please advise me as to why the following regex is not picking up the following string: "bob at gmail dot com"?

```
([a-zA-Z0-9|\\.]+)(\\s*?)[at|@|(at)](\\s*?)(\\w+)(\\s*?)[dot|\\.|dt](\\s*?)([\\w+]{1,3})
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
[at|@|(at)]
```

to:

```
(?:at|@|\(at\))
```

and

```
[dot|\\.|dt]
```

to

```
(?:dot|\\.|dt)
```

`[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `(?:...)` is a [non capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

The whole regex will be:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\\s*(?:at|@|\(at\))\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(?:do?t|\\.)\\s*(\\w+{1,3})
```

If you want to match subdomains:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\\s*(?:at|@|\(at\))\\s*(?:\\w+\\s*(?:do?t|\\.)\\s*)+(\\w+{1,3})
```

Comment: And `(?:dot|\\.|dt)` to `(?:do?t|\\.)` :p

Comment: Thank you very much... as follow up
I've written the above RegEx to pick up email addresses.

This successfully picks up bob at gmail dot come

However, it does not pick up, bob at gm dot gmail dot com (imaging the following email existed bob@gm.gmail.com)

Furthermore, it also generate some false positives if the word "at" is in the text. For instance the string "run at runtime. It" will return as an email run@runtime.it

Any suggestions on how to capture the second variant of the email and avoid capturing run@runtime.it?

Comment: @user3206133: see my edit. But, why `run@runtime.it` is not a valid address?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

`^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
      @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;`

Hope this helps you

or Else Use the Below Class

```
org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator
```

use the below method

`isValid(String email)` returns boolean

Comment: Doesn't match `abc@com` that is a valid address, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: And wouldn't even match what OP asked for `bob at gmail dot com`.