# RegEx in Java for Email Matching

Tags: java, regex, email

([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\s*(?: at |@|( at ))\s*(\w+)\s*(?:do?t|\.)\s*(\w+)(\s*(?:do?t|\.)\s*(\w+))?

I've written the above RegEx to pick up email addresses.

This successfully picks up bob at gmail dot come

However, it does not pick up, bob at gm dot gmail dot com (imaging the following email existed bob@gm.gmail.com)

Furthermore, it also generate some false positives if the word "at" is in the text. For instance the string "run at runtime. It" will return as an email run@runtime.it

Any suggestions on how to capture the second variant of the email and avoid capturing run@runtime.it?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel ? Use `EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(emailAddr)` from apache commons. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html#isValid(java.lang.String)

Comment: @user2336315 - thanks. but, its also good to try it yourself. or see apache source code.

Comment: also have a look at the related questions on the right

Comment: You can see a regex to validate an RFC822-compliant e-mail address [here](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), but then you might realize that a regex probably isn't the right tool to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183351/java-regex-for-email-detection) submitted by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

please see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

possibly try the expression --> ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil| biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for doing this:

1. Don't. There are many reasons why it will potentially fail. Best way to find out if it is a valid email address is by actually sending an email. Or did you know that `mail+tag@example.com` is a valid address? There are many more examples. [See here](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)
2. Don't do it yourself, re-use an existing library like apache commons or something

Comment: While I agree with the points you make, the OP is probably trying to pick up email addresses whose @ and . are replaced by "at" and "dot".